# What is no information rate in confusionMatrix in r?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, confusion-matrix

I wrote a logistic regression and used confusionMatrix function of caret library to check the accuracy of this model.
Here is my code.

```
library(caret)
fit=glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2+Lag3+Lag4+Lag5+Volume,data=Weekly,family=binomial)
predicted <- factor(ifelse(predict(fit, type = "response") < 0.5, "Down", "Up"))
confusionMatrix(predicted, Weekly$Direction, positive = "Up")


Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction Down  Up
      Down   54  48
      Up    430 557
                                         
               Accuracy : 0.5611         
                 95% CI : (0.531, 0.5908)
    No Information Rate : 0.5556         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.369          
                                         
                  Kappa : 0.035          
                                         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16         
                                         
            Sensitivity : 0.9207         
            Specificity : 0.1116         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.5643         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.5294         
             Prevalence : 0.5556         
         Detection Rate : 0.5115         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.9063         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.5161         
                                         
       'Positive' Class : Up
```

There are many information in confusionMatrix function. I can't understand the meaning of `No Information Rage` and `P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.369`.
Can anyone help me ,please?

Comment: Searching on "caret no information rate" brings up https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html. (The p-value note seems fairly self explanatory. Perhaps you need to review your basic statistics.)

Comment: @IRTFM  I know what is p-value in statistics, but p-value[Acc > NIR] is different from p-value and it is not in statistics, please see this question carefully.

Comment: This is the link in SO's [ask] page about research efforts expected: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253407/how-to-calculate-information-included-in-rs-confusion-matrix/253435#253435